# fetching client id in external javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to fetch Client ID's of asp.net control in external javascript file i google it but didn't find any relevant answer if somebody can tell me or provide me some good links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. The external javascript file is fetched as a separate request, so the page object with the control where the information is doesn't exist any more when the script is requested.

Comment: are there any work around what i am doing is writing thier full client id like ct100_something

Comment: @Mac: As you are using jQuery, you can add a class name to the control and use `$('.something')` to access the element.

Comment: ya but the problem there is there can be multiple element with same class

Comment: @Mac: You can have multiple classes on an element, so you can add a unique class to each element.